# How to detect focus in textbox in Adobe Air

Tags: apache-flex, air, textbox, focus

How can I detect when a particular textbox has gain focus, (both by keyboard and by mouse click). For example, when you click on a text box I just want a Alert popup.

I'm trying to do something like

```
protected function textbox1_changeHandler(event:Event):void
    {
          if(textbox1.IsFocus){
             //run some code
          }
    }
```

I know IsFocus doesn't exsist, but is there anything that will let me do the similar?

I'm using Flash Builder 4.6 and the component is mx:TextInput

Thanks

Comment: Just an FYI; the version of your IDE (AKA Flash Builder 4.6) is less useful than the version of the Flex SDK you're using.  In a lot of cases there are differences between different versions of Flex.  In this case, detecting focus is pretty consistent (see my answer)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the [focusIn](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/display/InteractiveObject.html#event%3afocusIn) event.

Conceptually like this:

```
<mx:TextInput focusIn="trace('received focus')"/>
```

---

If you want to find out if a textInput has has focus, you can use the [getFocus()](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/mx/core/UIComponent.html#getFocus%28%29) method.  Conceptually like this:

```
if(myComponent.getFocus() == myComponent){
 trace('component has focus');
} else {
 trace('component does not have focus');
}
```

Comment: What if I need to make it do something else instead of alert, is it still possible? I'll edit the question.

Comment: Yes, you can run any ActionScript code you wish in the focusIn handler.  The code I provided doesn't have anything to do with the Flex Alert class.